# How to incorporate dependency injection container into this project

Tags: php

I have tried for days to get this to work.

I am using this framework: https://github.com/DennisSkoko/discord-bot to create a bot. But I wan't to add the DIC container http://container.thephpleague.com/ to this project.

What I want to do is in the Main class is to register service providers (modules/packages/bundles) or whatever you want to call them, just like Laravel etc. does.

So I created a module/ dir and added a serviceprovider class and some other classes as the docs state: http://container.thephpleague.com/service-providers/

First I edited the start.php to inject the container:

```
use League\Container\Container;

require "vendor/autoload.php";
require "bot.php";

$container = new Container;

$main = new DS\Main(new Example($container));
$main->run();
```

I changed the Example bot to include a getContainer() function so I could read it from the Main class, like this:

```
use DS\Bot;
use Discord\Discord;
use DS\Service;

class Example extends Bot
{
    /**
     * Example constructor
     */
    public function __construct($container)
    {
        $this->config = [
            "token" => "My token"
        ];

        $this->container = $container;
    }


    /**
     * Will be executed when the WebSocket is ready and before the services are implemented.
     *
     * @param Discord $discord
     * 
     * @return void
     */
    public function setup(Discord $discord)
    {
        echo "Example is ready to start!";


    }


    public function getContainer()
    {
        return $this->container;
    }


    /**
     * Will return an array of Service that the bot uses.
     *
     * @return Service[]
     */
    public function getServices()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

I then changed the Main class to to register my service provider.

```
namespace DS;

use Discord\Discord;

/**
 * A class that bring bots script into life.
 */
class Main
{
    /**
     * @var Discord
     */
    private $discord;

    /**
     * @var Bot
     */
    private $bot;


    /**
     * Main constructor.
     *
     * @param Bot $bot
     */
    public function __construct(Bot $bot)
    {
        $this->bot = $bot;

        $this->discord = new Discord($this->bot->getConfig());

        $this->discord->on("ready", function ($discord) {
            $this->bot->setup($discord);
            $this->setServices($this->bot->getServices());
        });

        $this->container = $this->bot->getContainer();
        $this->container->addServiceProvider('Mynamespace\HelloWorld\ServiceProvider');

    }


    /**
     * Will run the bot.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $this->discord->run();
    }


    /**
     * Will add the services for the WebSocket.
     *
     * @param Service[] $services
     *
     * @return void
     */
    private function setServices($services)
    {
        foreach ($services as $service) {
            $this->discord->on($service->getEvent(), $service->getListener());
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the problem:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'A service provider must be a fully qualified class name or instance of (\League\Container\ServiceProvider\ServiceProviderInterface)'
```

Which is weird because I did it just like in the documentation and extended League\Container\ServiceProvider\AbstractServiceProvider

This I have double checked 20 times.

So I have no idea what to do about this. How can I use addServiceProvider() in the Main class and register things in the DIC?

I do not really want to do it in the Example class if possible. Because that should be extended by the user and the Main class will bootstrap the bot.

I also tried $this->bot->addServiceProvider() but then I get the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Example::addServiceProvider()
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: extended `League\Container\ServiceProvider\AbstractServiceProvider` or `\League\Container\ServiceProvider\AbstractServiceProvider` ?

Comment: Have you posted this issue on their github page?

Comment: @Progrock use League\Container\ServiceProvider\AbstractServiceProvider;

Comment: @Lasith No, I am obviously doing something wrong. I don't think the packages are at fault.

Comment: Seems like your service provider not implementing `\League\Container\ServiceProvider\ServiceProviderInterface`

Comment: Yes check this: Mynamespace\HelloWorld\ServiceProvider

Comment: (Not sure I like having that container passed all over the place and the editing of DS\Main.  Also you may want to define your properties, it's hard to follow.)

Comment: My serviceprovider looks *exactly* like this: http://container.thephpleague.com/service-providers/ I am editing Main because I want to fork this framework and add the DIC to it. But I can't get it working.